# Custom Snackbar width is not setting MATCH_PARENT in Tablets

Tags: android

Snackbar width is matching to full width in mobiles but its not setting match_parent when running in tablet. Kindly help me!Code is below

```
final Snackbar mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) mSnackbar.getView();
layout.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
TextView textView = (TextView) 
layout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
snackView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.snackbar_layout, null);
layout.addView(snackView, 0);
```

Comment: design that particular xml for tablet sperately and give width `match_parent`

Comment: that also not working. Its default behavior of Snackbar. let me know if you have any other idea.

Comment: get layout-param of Snackbar and set width to match parent

Answer (score 15):

Use the following code snippet to support full width in tablet landscape mode:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Sample Text", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction("Sample Text", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
(snackbar.getView()).getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
snackbar.show();
```

Comment: You made my day... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the default behavior of `snackbar` on tablets.for more information [look here](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/android-snackbar-design-support-library.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you use this theme:

```
"Theme.MaterialComponents"
```

the snackbar has margin and rounded corner.

To remove margin:

```
View viewInSnk = snkbr.getView();
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) snkbr.getView().getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
snkbr.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
```

and to remove round corner:

```
viewInSnk.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.snackbar_shape));
```

and for shape :

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#313131"/>
    <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below code:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
        .make(findViewById(put_your_parent_layout_id), "Try again!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            }
        });
snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
TextView textView = (TextView) snackbar.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
snackbar.show();
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain, **in detail**, how this addresses the question. For example, what in this code affects the width of the `Snackbar`?

Comment: The first parameter to `make()` is not a layout ID. It is a `View`. That `View` is only used to find the `CoordinatorLayout` that the `Snackbar` goes in (or the window's decor view if there is no `CoordinatorLayout`). The passed-in `View` is not used for anything else, and it has no impact on the width of the `Snackbar`. See [the source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.java#L132-L149).

Comment: @CommonsWare I believe you were asking for an explanation of the **answer**. It is a relatively common mistake to confuse when a reference is required and when it can be acquired by the method (See [Toast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast)). While your link is no longer valid, the anchor view has some influence over the SnackBar placement and size. This is likely what was being attempted, albeit poorly explained.